# Can I Pass value from form to popup window, display something based on what was passed, then pass something back?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I need to do this using PHP and Javascript.

I have one form, with a few inputs. One of them is gender.

When they click a link/button I need to pass the value of the gender drop down to a popup.

Based on that value I show either male or females portraits.

I'd like to pass the value back to the parent window once they select a portrait and then click a button.

I have the code to display the portaits. But how do I pass the values back and forth, and how do I make a value passed from the parent window available to my PHP code in the new popup?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is well defined, but the question itself is still somewhat vague.  I'll give it a shot though.  If you really mean a pop-up (separate window) rather than an on-page dialog (such as jQuery UI elements and so forth), then the communication channel you'll want to use is the object returned from `window.open()` to communicate from parent page to child page, and `window.opener` to communicate from child to parent.  For example:

```
var genderPicker = document.getElementById('genderSelect');
var gender = genderPicker.options[genderPicker.selectedIndex].value;
var portraitChooserWindow = window.open("path/to/script.ext?gender=" + gender);
// portraitChooserWindow is now a reference to the newly opened pop-up (or null if the browser blocked pop-ups)
```

From the child window, `window.opener` is now a reference to the parent window.

Comment: This did work, but then I decided to use JS to display the content directly into a div on the form once the gender is selected instead